# Cross-browser support / implementation of HTTP status codes

Tags: cross-browser, http-status-codes

I'd really like to know whether there's a comprehensive list of cross-browser support for the various HTTP status codes (particularly the ones in the 300s).

Does someone here know of a good write-up on that matter or maybe wants to share his knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have to answer my own question here, though the research didn't provide a whole lot of usefull stuff. The best I could find was [Redirect in response to POST transaction](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html), which seems a little bit outdated.

After all, I'll have to compile a list myself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Did you manage to compile such a list for more modern browsers? Would you care to share it? It still seems hard to find any reference for this.